# simplification of functional sum

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, sequences-and-series

I have the following infinite sum which seems to be familiar so I was wondering if it admits a possible simplification ! 
$$
\sum_{k\geq 0}\left( g(x_k,x_{k+1})-g(x_k,x_k)\right)
$$
where $g$ is only a continuous function from $\mathbb{R}\times\mathbb{R}$ to $\mathbb{R}$.

thank you for your time :)

Comment: Are the two terms both in the summation.  If so you ought to put the summand into parentheses.

Comment: thanks I've made an edit :)

Comment: In the first term you don't mean $g(x_{k+1},x_{k+1})$ do you? If that wasthe case than the sum would simplify to $\sum_{k\geq0} = g(x_0,x_0)-g(X,X)$, where $X=\lim_{k\to \infty} x_k$.

Comment: unfortunaly it's not the case :/

Comment: I think we need more information about $g(.)$, in particular is it bounded, increasing or decreasing function.

Comment: I'm afraid the only thing I know about $g$ is the continuity but what would happen if it gots one of the properties you mentioned ?